# AD7849 is it burned?

Tags: arduino, dac

I made a terrible mistake connecting -15VDC to the pin 18 of AD7849 instead of pin 17 and powered it up for a minute until i understood the problem.It was without the protection diode for power supply sequencing i realized later unfortunately.

I still have a bit of hope that i command it in a wrong way but not burn the chip.

I try to send data to it via Arduino Nano via SPI.

My connections are,

[image: schematic]

**Vdd is actually +15V It is written wrong in the schematic!**

**Pin 4 of AD7849 is connected to Arduino D9 which is wrong in the schematic!**

and test code is,

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define AD  9

 void setVoltage16(int dacpin, uint16_t mV)
{

   SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(8000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
   digitalWrite(dacpin,LOW);
   SPI.transfer(mV);
   digitalWrite(dacpin,HIGH);
   SPI.endTransaction();

 }
 void setup() {

   pinMode(AD, OUTPUT);
   SPI.begin();

 }
 void loop() {

  setVoltage16(AD,0xFFFF);
  delay(500);
  setVoltage16(AD,0x0000);

 }
```

the output i get from Vout of DAC is around 0v and some high very high freq noise.

Am i on the right way or should i put this chip to trash in despair? :)

Comment: Vdd is usually positive, and the datasheet says it might be +15V nominal. Your schematic shows it as -15V. I can't tell if the chip is fried, but you might be powering it wrong.

Comment: I am sorry! This is my distraction actually Vdd was positive in my schematic i drew that wrong. I have edited the question.

Comment: Pin 18 is NC, meaning **N**ot **C**connected so connecting 15 V to it should not damage the IC.

Comment: I am sorry that I have misleaded you, I haven't connected -15VDC to Vdd, I drew the schematic wrong, I have edited the question.

Comment: Also, try using SPI.transfer16 instead of SPI.transfer. AFAIK transfer only transfers a single byte.

Comment: Also, the `dacpin` (`AD`) in the code is on pin 9, not pin 8 as it is in the schematic.

Comment: I am correcting those and trying  SPI.transfer16  then report back.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The Datasheet labels Pin-18 as 'No Connect. Leave unconnected.', which, technically, is not the same as "internally not connected, do as you please". I believe that it's entirely possible that this pin could be connected to some internal function of the IC which is not intended to be used and therefore undocumented, and it's possible that connecting -15V here could have damaged the IC.

Comment: @brhans You're right, it could be a "manufacturer only" pin. So anything could have happened if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks all of you! The chip seems ok! When I used SPI.transfer16 it worked. I didn't test the chip deeply yet so I don't know if it is damaged yet but at least it works now. Richard the Spacecat if you would post an answer that would be the accepted one. Sorry again for drawing the schematic fast and wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 17 (VDD) is expecting +15V not -15V, the datasheet states that if VCC comes up before VDD then the part will go into SCR latchup, and they suggest putting a diode in place to prevent this. Depending on how much current your 5V rail was able to produce you may or may not have damaged the part by applying VCC without VDD.

However if you applied -15V to pin 17 for a minute then I would very much expect the part to be damaged.

Comment: I haven't connected -15VDC to Vdd, I am now powering up with the sequence,  VDD, VSS, and then VCC, I will try SPI.transfer16 as Richard the Spacecat says and report back.